# How can I delay 3s to search after input, Using UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I need it to search after it has stoped input 3s,

but this func run at once when user type the keyboard,

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
```

How can I delay 3s to run this func, so when user input another character i can stop the pre search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method to delay your action .

```
    [self performSelector:@selector(doStuff) withObject:myObj afterDelay:3.f];
```

Comment: I had using this method ,but when but it still need to update the ui by :    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
        [fileSearchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    });

Answer (score 2):

Start an `NSTimer` when the user enters the first character, each time the user enters another character, `invalidate` and restart the timer. When the timer fires, execute your search and update the UI.